# Tileable Landscape geometry nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes

Any idea how to join neighbouring vertices? I need a tileable landscape using Geomtery Nodes.

[image]

Comment: You should make the geometry tile-able in the first place.  Simply joining does not seem to be a good solution for this. It will be visible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what about this node setup? is this what you are looking for?

[image]

Comment: Works greate ! Thanks

Comment: @MateuszHanula But this is not a "tileable" landscape. ...this is simply a split landscape and thus the answer does not match the title of the question. ...just mentioned in passing.

Comment: @MateuszHanula : you are welcome

Answer (score 3):

To be able to piece a part together seamlessly, you need a "Seamless Pattern".

You can achieve this as follows:

[image]

1. Create a *Grid*. This has its center at the coordinates $(0,0,0)$ and extends automatically in all four directions.
2. By converting the position of the points with the *Vector Math* node `Absolute` into a positive range, you get useful coordinates for your `Noise Texture`. This will create a seamless structure from the center to the edge of the grid.
3. Then you just have to move the positions of the *Grid* and duplicate the part.

**But note:** To create a really seamless structure with smoothed normals, you have to connect the edge points (either directly in *Geometry Nodes*, or afterwards with a modifier), because only this way the normals will appear smooth over the whole mesh. After that you could apply a subdivision.

[image]
<sub>*(Blender 3.1+)*</sub>