# How to create a Seamless tileable triangular plane?

Tags: modeling, mesh, geometry-nodes

I have a problem with creating a Seamless tileable triangular plane in Blender. This is what I created in Blender:

[image: my triangular plane]

As you can see, this is not a tileable plane. How can I achieve that? Is it possible?

Also, you need to know that I don't use Geometry Nodes, because I don't know anything about that. But if your solution is about Geometry Node, please give me a resource or a simple example.

**Update**:
I need to create a tileable plane to make a texture by that to export them into UE

see this example :

https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/273006

@quellenform has created a tile mesh. But this is not a triangular mesh. I need something like that but with a triangle. I tried to change that but I can't success

Comment: What do you mean by "seamless"? Do you want to tile it?

Comment: can you add a drawing of how you want the final output to look like so we can understand what you mean by "seamless"

Comment: By 'Seamless', do you mean 'flat', 'with straight sides', or somesuch? Please clarify.

Comment: @indiedeveloper you were missing the word "tileable" in your post, so now that you have clarified that, I have updated your post to reflect this. It would be good to know why you want to do that because maybe there is a better solution than using bad topology. Maybe you should use a tileable triangulated texture instead so you can stick with clean quad topology.

Comment: *"But this is not a triangular mesh"* - you literally just need to insert "Triangulate" node after the left "Grid" node.

Answer (score 3):

This is the simplest workflow I could come up with (also while I swear I've done that in the past using sculpting and tileable settings, I couldn't figure how to do it today…)

1. In the new file <kbd>A</kbd><kbd>X</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> to delete everything.
2. <kbd>⬆ Shift</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>M</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> Add a *Plane*.
3. <kbd>Numpad 7</kbd> *Top Orthographic View*.
4. **<kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd>**<kbd>D</kbd> For ***Linked** Duplicate*, <kbd>X</kbd><kbd>2</kbd><kbd>↩ Enter</kbd> to offset to the right.
5. <kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd><kbd>D</kbd>, <kbd>X</kbd><kbd>-</kbd><kbd>4</kbd><kbd>↩ Enter</kbd> this time offset to the left (of the original plane).
6. <kbd>A</kbd> *Select All*, <kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd><kbd>D</kbd>, <kbd>Y</kbd><kbd>2</kbd><kbd>↩ Enter</kbd>, <kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd><kbd>D</kbd>, <kbd>Y</kbd><kbd>-</kbd><kbd>4</kbd><kbd>↩ Enter</kbd>.

If you use Autohotkey, you can just run a macro like this:

```
F12:: Send axdAmp{Numpad7}!dx2{Enter}!dx-4{Enter}a!dy2{Enter}!dy-4{Enter}
```

[image]

7. Select the middle (original) tile.
8. <kbd>⭾ Tab</kbd> *Edit Mode*.
9. <kbd>1</kbd> *Vertex Selection Mode*.
10. Select bottom-right vert and <kbd>X</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> delete it.
11. <kbd>A</kbd> Select All.
12. $\color{#888}{█0}\color{green}{█}$ *right click*, <kbd>S</kbd> Subdivide; <kbd>F9</kbd> adjust the number of cuts (I've chosen 10).
13. Enable the *Proportional Editing*, **Random** with very big *Proportional Size*:

[image]

14. For convenience select two endpoints (top-right and bottom-left) and <kbd>H</kbd> hide them.
15. Select any vertex and <kbd>G</kbd> *Move* it a little bit **up and left**, you can use $\color{#888}{█}\color{green}⬇\color{#888}{█}$ *mouse wheel down* (**not up**, as it will decrease to small size rather quickly) to change the randomization seed to find something you like.
16. Do the same but now <kbd>G</kbd> *Move* **down and right** by about the same distance.

[image]

17. Use $\color{#888}{█}\color{green}0\color{#888}{█}$ *middle mouse button* to freely change the view and then repeat the last steps to <kbd>G</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> randomly move up and down.
18. <kbd>O</kbd> Disable *Proportional Editing*.
19. Enable Vertex Snapping:

[image]

20. <kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd><kbd>H</kbd> reveal two hidden vertices.
21. Localize the original top-left corner. It could be easier if you assigned it to a vertex group earlier, but you could also select the endpoints (just revealed), and press <kbd>✲ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Numpad +</kbd> to *Select More* until all but one vertices are selected (and then <kbd>✲ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>`I`</kbd> to *Invert Selection*).
22. Might be a good idea to move this top-left corner vertex a little bit to the top-left to really be a corner.
23. Now <kbd>G</kbd> *Move* the endpoints to their nearest copy of the top-left corner:

[image]

23. It's already tiled, you just need to copy the repeating left border to the right, and top border to the bottom and by <kbd>⬆ Shift</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> duplicating them and <kbd>A</kbd><kbd>M</kbd><kbd>B</kbd> *Merging by Distance*:

[image]

24. And finally <kbd>A</kbd> *Select All* and use <kbd>F3</kbd> `Grid Fill`.
25. <kbd>F9</kbd> Adjust the number of cuts to be the same as in p. 12.
26. <kbd>✲ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>T</kbd> *Triangulate*.

[image]

27. If you wanted a flatter tile, rather than going back to p. 17. you can just <kbd>A</kbd><kbd>S</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd>:

[image]

28. You could also select the rim by going to <kbd>2</kbd> *Edge Selection Mode*, selecting one edge that surely is **inside**, then <kbd>⬆ Shift</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> *Select Similar*, by <kbd>A</kbd> *Amount of Faces Around an Edge*,  and <kbd>✲ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>`I`</kbd> *Invert Selection*, then add it to a vertex group, add a modifier using an inversion of this vertex group, then <kbd>⬆ Shift</kbd>$\color{green}{█}\color{#888}{0█}$ *drag* select other tiles and <kbd>✲ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>L</kbd>, <kbd>P</kbd> to *Copy Modifiers* - but you would get a better effect just randomly displacing less to begin with…

### Rendering to a Texture

Simply position a camera with no rotation (looking straight down), above the surface, somewhere close to the Z axis (XY close to origin), though it doesn't have to be exactly at the center (because there are no seams anyway), set camera type to orthographic, scale to $2$ (based on the dimensions of the plane), output resolution to equal width and height (again based on the dimensions of the plane) add a Sun light, render.

[image]

Comment: @indiedeveloper you absolutely can. Not sure if you want an image, but even then rendering the tile from the top with orthographic camera and the right lightning (Sun or just shadeless) will yield a seamlessly tiling texture.

Answer (score -3):

If you're just trying to make a triangle shaped plane, do the following:

1. add a "plane"
2. go to edit mode and select two vertices
   [image: two vertices selected]
3. Type 'm' and select 'merge at center'
   [image: merge at center]
4. Done
   [image]

Comment: just search for "What is a Seamless Texture (Tileable Texture)?" in google. but in my case i need "Seamless triangular plane"